# Где отображается результат  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ?

Tags: windowsphone, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7

Где отображается результат  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ?
Есть ли более лучшие решения для вывода результатов при Debug? Может нечто похожее на работу NSLog в objective-c

Answer (score 2):

В отладчике, конечно.

Если вы запускаете приложение без отладчика (зачем?), вы можете сконфигурировать его так, чтобы log скидывался в консоль или в файл. Пример (украден [отсюда](http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/?p=312), добавлять в `app.config`):

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="TestTrace"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData="trace.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
   ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Более общий ответ: результаты вывода отображаются в подключенных listener'ах. В частности, отладчик является одним из слушателей. Если отладчика нет, то можно подключить вывод в файл.

Comment: @andreycha: на десктопе есть ещё [`DebugView`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) (он регистрируется как listener).